# Excel VBA cannot complete an export in xlsx from SAP

Tags: excel, vba, save, xlsx, sap-gui

I'm an absolute beginner in Sap script and just a beginner in Excel Vba (my scarse knowledge comes mostly from your kind community), so be patient.

I'm trying to launch from Excel Vba a data estraction in Sap and save the export in a xlsx file.
While I can complete the file save in txt I cannot do so in xlsx. It stops in the Sap window "save" waiting, despite having given a file name, path and return:
[image: here where it stops]

I give you here the code, with export xlsx routine (where I need your help) and with the txt output (that woorks):

```
enter code here
Public Sub SAP_Export()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection


'This My SAP Script - it does't matter, can be any Sap script:
'/////
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "zbrgcogeban" 'transaction name
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CONTO-LOW").Text = "69314*" 'variable
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CONTO-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CONTO-LOW").CaretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
'/////

GoTo SAVEASXLSX

'****THIS SAVE AS TXT...THIS WORKS!..********
'Click the export to file button
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[45]").press 'SAVE LIST IN FILE...txt


'Choose the export format
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI- SELFLAG[1,0]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

'Choose the export filename and path
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "test.txt"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\appo\"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press    'Export the file

SAVEASXLSX:
'THIS SHOULD SAVE AS XLSX BUT IT DOESN'T WORK, IT REMAIN ON THE "SAVE AS" WINDOW WAITING SOMEONE PRESSING "SAVE" BUTTON:

session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select 'open "save as xlsx" as selecting in Sap menu: List->Export->Spreadsheet
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "test.xlsx" 'file name
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\appo\"   'path name
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
End Sub
```

Comment: Check [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/). Maybe it helps. Also  [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/63bd20104af84112973ad59590645513/760.01/en-US/7ddb7c9c4a4c43219a65eee4ca8db001.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Storax you make my day!! It has been enough to untick "Native MS windows dialogs" to resume the xlsx salve. I'd like to tanks you and put solved to the post (I must find a way to do this, this is my first questions in Stackoverlow).

Do you know how to avoid that the Xlsx exported Sap file open it self in Excel after dowload? Is it an option that I have to select in Sap option or I must write a code in the script?

Comment: For any different question, please ask a new question.

Comment: @TheGrill Firenze: You are welcome. AFAIK there is no setting within SAPGUI/SAP to prevent SAP from opening the just downloaded file. I usuallay have a piece of code which closes the file but this code is not totally trivial as the file is opened asynchronously and also might be opened in another instance of excel.